# How to get a line break inside a <mx:GridItem> tag in flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml

I am a newbie to Flex and I am stuck in this since hours.

The mxml file structure that I have is as follows :-

```
<mx:Grid>
.
.
.
<mx:GridRow>
<mx:GridItem>
     <mx:Text text="blah blah" visible="some condition"/>
     <mx:Repeater dataprovider="something something" visible="xyz">
          <AnotherFileCalled paddingLeft = "5">
     </mx:Repeater>
</mx:GridItem>
```

AnotherFileCalled is another mxml file that is getting data and this data is visible in the current mxml file.

So my question is how do I show each item from other file on a new line. I want to make sure every item coming from other file is shown on a new file. So how do I get this. I have tried using another Grid inside the Repeater and also tried using  after each item, at every possible place. But I am not able to view each item from the external file on a new line.

The content that is visible to me right now is :-

Lets assume another file gets me information about the email addresses. So my work email, personal email can be listed from this file.

Currently it is visible as

```
Personal - asd@gmail.com Work - asdasdas@gmail.com
```

I want it to be visible as :-

```
Personal - asd@gmail.com 
Work - asdasdas@gmail.com
```

Thanks for your time.

Zingo

Comment: I see your latest edit showing the desired layout. You should be able to use the info in my answer to do this by slightly re-arranging the contents of your grid item. You might need to use an HBox, be careful about nesting too many boxes inside your grid, the scrolling performance may suffer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/GridItem.html) says about layout in a `GridItem`:

> The GridItem container defines a grid cell in GridRow container. (The GridRow container, in turn, defines a row in a Grid container.) The GridItem container can contain any number of children, which are laid out as in an HBox container. If you do not want HBox layout, create a container, such as a VBox container, as a child of the GridItem control and put other components in this child container.

So you might try:

```
<mx:GridItem>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Text text="blah blah" visible="some condition"/>
        <mx:Repeater dataprovider="something something" visible="xyz">
            <AnotherFileCalled paddingLeft = "5">
        </mx:Repeater>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:GridItem>
```

or

```
<mx:GridItem>
    <mx:Text text="blah blah" visible="some condition"/>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Repeater dataprovider="something something" visible="xyz">
            <AnotherFileCalled paddingLeft = "5">
        </mx:Repeater>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:GridItem>
```